# import CSV file into postgres using django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, csv

I am trying to import csv file into postgres DB using Django .

I try following function:

```
import os
from django.db import models
import psycopg2
from postgres_copy import CopyMapping

host = 'localhost'
port = '5432'
dbname = 'sellerhub'
username = 'postgres'
password = 'postgres'


class Reports:
    def __init__(self):
        global host, port, dbname, username, password
        try:
            self.db_conn = psycopg2.connect("host=%s port=%s dbname=%s user=%s password=%s" %(host, port, dbname, username, password))
        except psycopg2.OperationalError:
            print "Database Not Found Or the Credentials are wrong."
        self.cur = self.db_conn.cursor()
def saveUploadedInventory(self, inventory_file):
        #print "Inventory File"
        with open('uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv','wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in inventory_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
        #print "Inventory Saved."
        copy_sql = """copy fk_invent_temp from stdin WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER as ',' """
        #print "query created"
        with open('uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv','r') as pmt_file:
            self.cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=pmt_file)
        #print "file uploades"
        os.system('rm uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv')
        #print "removes file"
```

and **setting.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'sellerhub',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

this function is executed completly with no error,

but there is no data in fk_invent table .

If i directly import that file using PGAdmin3 UI that is uploaded successfully .
Pls any body can tell what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: There's too much missing information. What class is this a method of? What is `self.cur` and `self.cur.copy_expert`?

Comment: cur is the Connection from database and copy expert is for copying database

Comment: But without seeing the code for copy_expert, how can we know where it is going wrong?

Comment: Does your Postgres user (specified in settings.py) have superuser rights? Must be superuser to COPY to or from a file...

Comment: @AtlasStrategic ya its have superuser rights .

Comment: "You must have select privilege on the table whose values are read by COPY TO, and insert privilege on the table into which values are inserted by COPY FROM. It is sufficient to have column privileges on the column(s) listed in the command." -- quote from [COPY -- copy data between a file and a table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html) - there is no need to be superuser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get temporary solution by inserting line by line:

```
with open('uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv','wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in inventory_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
        print "Inventory Saved."
        reader = csv.reader(open('uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv','rb'))
        count = 0 
        for row in reader:
            if count == 0:
                count=1
                continue
            # print row[0],"\n"
            count = count +1
            try:
                self.cur.execute("""INSERT into  fk_payment_temp values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10],row[11],row[12],row[13],row[14],row[15],row[16],row[17],row[18],row[19],row[20],row[21],row[22],row[23],row[24],row[25],row[26],row[27],row[28],row[29],row[30],row[31],row[32],row[33],row[34],row[35],row[36],row[37],row[38],row[39],row[40],row[41],row[42],row[43],row[44]))
                print "INSERT into  fk_payment_temp values('",row[0],"','",row[1],"''",row[2],"','",row[3],"''",row[4],"','",row[5],"''",row[6],"','",row[7],"''",row[8],"','",row[9],"''",row[10],"','",row[11],"''",row[12],"','",row[13],"''",row[14],"','",row[15],"''",row[16],"','",row[17],"''",row[18],"','",row[19],"''",row[20],"','",row[21],"''",row[22],"','",row[23],"''",row[24],"','",row[25],"''",row[26],"','",row[27],"''",row[28],"','",row[29],"''",row[30],"','",row[31],"''",row[32],"','",row[33],"''",row[34],"','",row[35],"''",row[36],"','",row[37],"''",row[38],"','",row[39],"''",row[40],"','",row[41],"''",row[42],"','",row[43],"''",row[44],"','",row[45],"')"
            except:
                pass
        print count
        self.cur.callproc("flip_payment_test")
        self.cur
        self.db_conn.commit()

        print "file uploades"
        os.system('rm uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv')
        print "removes file"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and cleanest solution is to import a `json` fixture file with Django `manage.py` command. So I'd recommend you converting your `CSV` file to `json` and load it to database with `manage.py loaddata` command:

```
python manage.py loaddata yourfile.json
```

You can find CSV to json converters all over the Internet.

Comment: csv file is selected by user that is not specific